# Copying files from AWS s3 (SSE) bucket to google cloud

Tags: amazon-s3, google-cloud-storage, boto, gsutil

We were trying to copy some data from a S3 bucket to google cloud storage. However, the gsutil copy command results in the following error:

```
gsutil cp s3://my_s3_bucket/datadir1 gs://my_google_bucket
```

Error:

```
Requests specifying Server Side Encryption with AWS KMS managed keys require AWS Signature Version 4
```

Is there a way to get around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest version of gsutil supports AWS Signature Version 4 for calls to S3, but you'll need to explicitly enable it.

First, update to the latest version of gsutil (you'll need 4.28 or higher). In the `[S3]` section of your ".boto" configuration file, set these parameters:

```
[s3]
use-sigv4 = True
host = s3.<some AWS region>.amazonaws.com
```